# Ignore encoding error if unable to encode

Tags: python

I wanted to know if there's a way to ignore it if the latin1 can't encode and ignore the errors?

This when I'm going to save to a csv file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g9SE.png)

Comment: Always provide code as a text, as a minimum reproducible code. For your problem I suggest you reading file first so you can [try this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616678/unicodedecodeerror-in-python-when-reading-a-file-how-to-ignore-the-error-and-ju)

Comment: What's the purpose to use `latin1` if this encoding doesn't contain all chars you need? Choose encoding which fits your requirements.

Comment: I have a system here that only accepts with latin1 Olivin Roght

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/19170534)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the keyword argument `errors='ignore'` to the `DataFrame.to_csv` method to ignore encoding/decoding errors. More info can be found in [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Comment: Note: the parameter `errors` was added since version `1.1.0.`