# 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Python 3 error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```py
import imaplib
from email.parser import HeaderParser

conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
conn.login('example@gmail.com', 'password')
conn.select()
conn.search(None, 'ALL')
data = conn.fetch('1', '(BODY[HEADER])')
header_data = data[1][0][1].decode('utf-8')
```

At this point I get the error message:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Python 3 doesn't have str.decode() anymore, so how can I fix this?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think the other version is better overall. I don't really get why both questions attracted an answer concerning PyJWT, though. That seems like it belongs on a separate question - one which might not be suitable for Stack Overflow, as it's essentially tech support for that library.

Answer (score 296, accepted):

You are trying to decode an object that is *already decoded*. You have a `str`, there is no need to decode from UTF-8 anymore.

Simply drop the `.decode('utf-8')` part:

```
header_data = data[1][0][1]
```

Comment: Is there a simple way to do this conditionally? (I only want to decode if the message is encoded.)

Comment: @devinbost: in Python 3? Test for the object type or the `decode` attribute, *or* just catch the exception. `try: data = data.decode('...') except AttributeError: pass`.

Comment: @devinbost: however, you are usually better off decoding closer to the source of your data, where you'll usually know exactly what you have.

Answer (score 73):

If you land here using jwt authentication after the PyJWT v2.0.0 release (22/12/2020), you might want to freeze your version of PyJWT to the previous release in your `requirements.txt` file.

```
PyJWT==1.7.1
```

Comment: GIVE THIS PERSON A MEDAL!!!!

This was a dependency in our enviroments `rest_framework_simplejwt` package and was causing the issue.

Comment: Not a safe solution: see CVE-2022-29217 that affects PyJWT 1.x versions:   https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/security/advisories/GHSA-ffqj-6fqr-9h24

Answer (score 56):

Begining with Python 3, all strings are unicode objects.

```
  a = 'Happy New Year' # Python 3
  b = unicode('Happy New Year') # Python 2
```

The instructions above are the same. So I think you should remove the `.decode('utf-8')` part because you  already have a unicode object.

Answer (score 53):

Use it by this Method:

```
str.encode().decode()
```

Comment: `bytearray(str, 'encoding').decode('another_encoding')` would do the job if you need to decode `idna` or any other encoding

Comment: This is useless. You are encoding to UTF-8, then decoding the resulting bytes as UTF-8, ending up where you started. You are keeping the CPU warm with no other benefit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "ending up where you started" - not if you have escape sequences in your string, for example:

>>> '\u0159'.encode().decode()
'ř'

Comment: @Peter: no, you don't need encoding or decoding for that. `'\u0159'` prints the exact same output. You are confusing the string literal syntax with the canonical representation of the value.

Comment: You can directly use, There is no need to encode and then decode again.

Comment: At the time of writing, 43 people upvoted a comment saying that this answer post is useless, but only 10 people downvoted the answer post.

Comment: @Peter was right.... If this is useless, what's the proper way to decode escaped sequences? i only found '\\u2026'.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')

Answer (score 33):

In Python 3, this mental model is pretty straight-forward:

- *Encoding* is the process of converting a `str` to a `bytes` object
- *Decoding* is the process of converting a `bytes` object to a `str`

```
┏━━━━━━━┓                ┏━━━━━━━┓
┃       ┃ -> encoding -> ┃       ┃
┃  str  ┃                ┃ bytes ┃
┃       ┃ <- decoding <- ┃       ┃
┗━━━━━━━┛                ┗━━━━━━━┛
```

In your case, you are calling `data.decode("UTF-8")` , but the variable is already a `str` object and is already decoded. So just refer to `data` directly if a string is what you need.

Answer (score 20):

For Python3

```
html = """\\u003Cdiv id=\\u0022contenedor\\u0022\\u003E \\u003Ch2 class=\\u0022text-left m-b-2\\u0022\\u003EInformaci\\u00f3n del veh\\u00edculo de patente AA345AA\\u003C\\/h2\\u003E\\n\\n\\n\\n \\u003Cdiv class=\\u0022panel panel-default panel-disabled m-b-2\\u0022\\u003E\\n \\u003Cdiv class=\\u0022panel-body\\u0022\\u003E\\n \\u003Ch2 class=\\u0022table_title m-b-2\\u0022\\u003EInformaci\\u00f3n del Registro Automotor\\u003C\\/h2\\u003E\\n \\u003Cdiv class=\\u0022col-md-6\\u0022\\u003E\\n \\u003Clabel class=\\u0022control-label\\u0022\\u003ERegistro Seccional\\u003C\\/label\\u003E\\n \\u003Cp\\u003ESAN MIGUEL N\\u00b0 1\\u003C\\/p\\u003E\\n \\u003Clabel class=\\u0022control-label\\u0022\\u003EDirecci\\u00f3n\\u003C\\/label\\u003E\\n \\u003Cp\\u003EMAESTRO ANGEL D\\u0027ELIA 766\\u003C\\/p\\u003E\\n \\u003Clabel class=\\u0022control-label\\u0022\\u003EPiso\\u003C\\/label\\u003E\\n \\u003Cp\\u003EPB\\u003C\\/p\\u003E\\n \\u003Clabel class=\\u0022control-label\\u0022\\u003EDepartamento\\u003C\\/label\\u003E\\n \\u003Cp\\u003E-\\u003C\\/p\\u003E\\n \\u003Clabel class=\\u0022control-label\\u0022\\u003EC\\u00f3digo postal\\u003C\\/label\\u003E\\n \\u003Cp\\u003E1663\\u003C\\/p\\u003E\\n \\u003C\\/div\\u003E\\n \\u003Cdiv class=\\u0022col-md-6\\u0022\\u003E\\n \\u003Clabel class=\\u0022control-label\\u0022\\u003ELocalidad\\u003C\\/label\\u003E\\n \\u003Cp\\u003ESAN MIGUEL\\u003C\\/p\\u003E\\n \\u003Clabel class=\\u0022control-label\\u0022\\u003EProvincia\\u003C\\/label\\u003E\\n \\u003Cp\\u003EBUENOS AIRES\\u003C\\/p\\u003E\\n \\u003Clabel class=\\u0022control-label\\u0022\\u003ETel\\u00e9fono\\u003C\\/label\\u003E\\n \\u003Cp\\u003E(11)46646647\\u003C\\/p\\u003E\\n \\u003Clabel class=\\u0022control-label\\u0022\\u003EHorario\\u003C\\/label\\u003E\\n \\u003Cp\\u003E08:30 a 12:30\\u003C\\/p\\u003E\\n \\u003C\\/div\\u003E\\n \\u003C\\/div\\u003E\\n\\u003C\\/div\\u003E \\n\\n\\u003Cp class=\\u0022text-center m-t-3 m-b-1 hidden-print\\u0022\\u003E\\n \\u003Ca href=\\u0022javascript:window.print();\\u0022 class=\\u0022btn btn-default\\u0022\\u003EImprim\\u00ed la consulta\\u003C\\/a\\u003E \\u0026nbsp; \\u0026nbsp;\\n \\u003Ca href=\\u0022\\u0022 class=\\u0022btn use-ajax btn-primary\\u0022\\u003EHacer otra consulta\\u003C\\/a\\u003E\\n\\u003C\\/p\\u003E\\n\\u003C\\/div\\u003E"""
```

```
print(html.replace("\\/", "/").encode().decode('unicode_escape'))
```

Comment: What has this got to do with the question? Can you explain what your answer is doing?

Answer (score 17):

I'm not familiar with the library, but if your problem is that you don't want a byte array, one easy way is to specify an encoding type straight in a cast:

```
>>> my_byte_str
b'Hello World'

>>> str(my_byte_str, 'utf-8')
'Hello World'
```

Comment: They don’t have a `bytes` object to begin with, and `str(bytes_object, codec)` is just an alternative spelling for `bytes_object.decode(codec)`. Both fail if you really have a `str` instead.

Comment: You're right, this specific question does have a `str` already. This answer could still be useful to people in the future that may have byte arrays (this was the issue I faced when I originally stumbled upon this post).

Comment: I'm not sure how you stumbled on this post, however, because `my_byte_str.decode` exists and works, and will not throw the exception in the question.

Answer (score 8):

It s already decoded in Python3, Try directly it should work.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
html.replace("\\/", "/").encode().decode('unicode_escape', 'surrogatepass')
```

This is similar to json.loads(html) behaviour

Comment: That chain saved me, tried this solution randomly!

Comment: What has this got to do with the question? Can you explain what this code is doing?

Comment: This solution worked for me too. But can you please explain surrogatepass and unicode_escape params ? What do these parameters do ?

Answer (score 3):

Use codecs module's open() to read file:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as fdata:
```

Answer (score 3):

If anyone getting the same error while participating in Kaggle for a Logistic REgre, here is the solution :

```py
logmodel = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear')
```

Comment: How is this related to the question? I'm not sure it has anything to do with e-mails?

Answer (score 1):

Other answers sort of hint at it, but the problem may arise from expecting a bytes object.  In Python 3, decode is valid when you have an object of class bytes.  Running encode before decode may "fix" the problem, but it is a useless pair of operations that suggest the problem us upstream.

Answer (score 1):

I got **'str'** object has no attribute **'decode'** while creating `JWT access_token` using `Flask_JWT_extended` package.

To fix this issue, I upgraded my `Flask-JWT-Extended` package to `Flask-JWT-Extended==4.1.0`

For Reference:

Please Visit this page: https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 1):

First install suitable JWT

```
pip3 install PyJWT
```

then in your code

```
token.encode().decode('UTF-8')
```

this worked me, I think this will help you

Answer (score 0):

my case may have been a bit rare but I was working with django and my project was running locally but not when I deployed it, it seemed as though I was getting multiple dependency errors because I was doing: `pip freeze > requirements.txt` doing this fixed the issue:

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```