# how to return values from map function on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, python-module-unicodedata

I am trying to return values from map function but instead it gives me the memory address. I tried using list, but then it gives me an error stating str object doesn't have an attribute decode. Is there a way out?

Comment: Could you post the specific error messages?

Comment: Could you post an exemple of your dataframe?

Comment: posted error and dataframe example

Comment: well, you should format your example

Comment: done edited exmple

Answer (score 0):

The first problem you mentioned is probably because you are accessing an objects name rather than applying a method.

But for this error Error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

This error is already answered in here ['str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Python 3 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583565/str-object-has-no-attribute-decode-python-3-error)

As it said here you are trying to decode an object that is already decoded. You have a str, there is no need to decode from UTF-8 anymore. If you remove the .decode() method from your chain it will be ok.

Comment: i removed decode, it then throws str has no attribute unicodedata error.