# How to tokenize a text corpus?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, recommendation-engine

I want to tokenize a corpus of text using NLTK library.

My corpus looks like:

```
['Did you hear about the Native American man that drank 200 cups of tea?',
 "What's the best anti diarrheal prescription?",
 'What do you call a person who is outside a door and has no arms nor legs?',
 'Which Star Trek character is a member of the magic circle?',
 "What's the difference between a bullet and a human?",
```

I've tried:

```
tok_corp = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent.decode('utf-8')) for sent in corpus]
```

which raised:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Help would be appreaciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Python 3 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583565/str-object-has-no-attribute-decode-python-3-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this page](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/punkt.html#PunktLanguageVars.word_tokenize) suggests word_tokenize method expect a string as an argument, just try

```
tok_corp = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in corpus]
```

Edit: with the following code I can get the tokenized corpus,

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk import word_tokenize

corpus = ['Did you hear about the Native American man that drank 200 cups of tea?',
 "What's the best anti diarrheal prescription?",
 'What do you call a person who is outside a door and has no arms nor legs?',
 'Which Star Trek character is a member of the magic circle?',
 "What's the difference between a bullet and a human?"]


tok_corp = pd.DataFrame([word_tokenize(sent) for sent in corpus])
```

**Output:**

```
      0     1     2           3        4   ...    13    14    15    16    17
0    Did   you  hear       about      the  ...   tea     ?  None  None  None
1   What    's   the        best     anti  ...  None  None  None  None  None
2   What    do   you        call        a  ...    no  arms   nor  legs     ?
3  Which  Star  Trek   character       is  ...  None  None  None  None  None
4   What    's   the  difference  between  ...  None  None  None  None  None
```

I think there are some non-strings or non-byte-like objects sneaked in your corpus. I recommend you to check it again.

Comment: '''TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object''' To be honest, I'm just trying reproduce a code I've found on the web and I think the author's missing something there. I've tried to use nltk.sent_tokenize prior to word_tokenize but without a success.

Comment: is it possible that corpus which is a list might be containing some item other than string ? It would be great if you can debug the loop tbh.

Comment: It has '[' but that's a string too. It has occasionally a string, but again, as a string.

Answer (score 1):

The error is right there, `sent` doesn't have the attribute `decode`. You only need to `.decode()` them if they were first encoded, i.e., `bytes` objects instead of `str` objects. Remove that and it should be fine.

Comment: '''TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object''' To be honest, I'm just trying reproduce a code I've found on the web and I think the author's missing something there. I've tried to use nltk.sent_tokenize prior to word_tokenize but without a success.

Comment: What is the type of the elements in `corpus` then, and does it work with the smaller sample that you posted?

Comment: It has '[' but that's a string too. It has occasionally a string, but again, as a string.