# PILLOW throws `OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x08B3B060>`

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-imaging-library, captcha, decoding

I'm trying to extract texts from CAPTCHA pictures. The idea is to use lxml to get the image data from the form. The image data is prepended with a header that defines the data type. I'm guessing the [CAPTCHA picture](http://tracuunnt.gdt.gov.vn/tcnnt/mstdn.jsp) is a PNG image encoded in Base64. The image data is decoded from Base64 into the initial binary format. Meanwhile `PIL` wraps the binary data with `BytesIO` before it is passed to the `PIL.Image` class.
Here is the snippet's first section.

```
import lxml.html
import urllib.request as urllib2
import pprint
import http.cookiejar as cookielib
from io import BytesIO
import lxml.html
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

def parse_form(html):
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
    data = {}
    for e in tree.cssselect('form input'):
        if e.get('name'):
            data[e.get('name')] = e.get('value')
    return data

REGISTER_URL = 'http://tracuunnt.gdt.gov.vn/tcnnt/mstdn.jsp'
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
html = opener.open(REGISTER_URL).read()
form = parse_form(html)
```

Here, this function raises `OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x08B3B060>`:

```
def get_captcha(html):
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
    img_data = tree.cssselect('div img')[0].get('src')
    img_data = img_data.partition('-')[-1]
    binary_img_data = img_data.decode('base64')
    file_like = BytesIO(binary_img_data)
    img = Image.open(file_like)
    return img

img = get_captcha(html)
```

I'm suspecting that it is the `binary_img_data` variable. I've tried to read up on decoding, encoding, PIL doc, and binary data on how to PIL can possibly read a web-based image i.e CAPTCHA but got nothing helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Python 3 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583565/str-object-has-no-attribute-decode-python-3-error)

Answer (score 0):

To decode the base64 string, try the following:

```
from base64 import b64decode

binary_img_data = b64decode(img_data)
```

The method your code uses (`img_data.decode('base64')`) was valid in Python 2, but will not work in Python 3.

Comment: Thank you but it gives the error `OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0885B270>`

Answer (score 0):

Totally overlooked the solution at the beginning. `PILLOW` couldn't read the image in binary data with that logic so I simply called the content of `request.get()` that bears the image's binary form and called Pillow to open it on the fly with `BytesIO()`.

```
import lxml.html
import urllib.request as urllib2
from io import BytesIO
import lxml.html
from PIL import Image



   img_data = tree.cssselect('div img')[0].get('src')
   img_link = 'http://tracuunnt.gdt.gov.vn'+ img_data
   response = requests.get(img_link)
   img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
```