# Problen with generating token in login

Tags: python, django, jwt, token, http-status-code-500

Hello I would like help I have been trying to learn how to create token with django rest framework and pyjwt
But whenever I do it when I am going to use login it gives me an error I would like to know if it is due to the code since I have seen several videos and I have the same code or it is due to something on my computer and if so, how could I solve it, the error is the next

Internal Server Error: /api/login
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Users\ferna\Documents\Cursos\Youtube\auth.env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "D:\Users\ferna\Documents\Cursos\Youtube\auth.env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\Users\ferna\Documents\Cursos\Youtube\auth.env\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Users\ferna\Documents\Cursos\Youtube\auth.env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Users\ferna\Documents\Cursos\Youtube\auth.env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "D:\Users\ferna\Documents\Cursos\Youtube\auth.env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
File "D:\Users\ferna\Documents\Cursos\Youtube\auth.env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
raise exc
File "D:\Users\ferna\Documents\Cursos\Youtube\auth.env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Users\ferna\Documents\Cursos\Youtube\auth\users\views.py", line 37, in post
token = jwt.encode(payload, 'secret', algorithm='HS256').decode('utf-8')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
[07/May/2021 21:18:23] ←[35;1m"POST /api/login HTTP/1.1" 500 96900←[0m

the code for view it's

```html
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from .models import User
import jwt, datetime


# Create your views here.
class RegisterView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)


class LoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        email = request.data['email']
        password = request.data['password']

        user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()

        if user is None:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('User not found!')

        if not user.check_password(password):
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Incorrect password!')

        payload = {
            'id': user.id,
            'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
            'iat': datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        }

        token = jwt.encode(payload, 'secret', algorithm='HS256').decode('utf-8')

        response = Response()

        response.set_cookie(key='jwt', value=token, httponly=True)
        response.data = {
            'jwt': token
        }
        return response
```

Comment: Looks like the package `PyJWT` v2.0.0 has a bug. Try to change it's version.
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65484529/7285863

Answer (score 0):

I found actual problem.

The package `PyJWT` changed return type of `jwt.encode(...)` with version 2. From now it returns `string` instead of `byte string`. [Link](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html#jwt-encode-return-type)

After that use these codes:

```
encoded = jwt.encode({"some": "payload"}, key, algorithm="HS256")
result = jwt.decode(encoded, key, algorithms="HS256")
```

instead of that this:

```
result = jwt.encode(payload, 'secret', algorithm='HS256').decode('utf-8')
```