# Base64 to decimal

Tags: python, base64

Playing around with conversions in base64 with Python but I have hit a roadblock with trying to convert b64 to decimal.

The following code is suggested on stackoverflow previously but doesn't seem to work for me.

I looked up the error and it appears that this means it can't decode b6 because it is already decoded...

```
b6 = 'FhY='
print(' '.join([ str(ord(c)) for c in b6.decode('base64') ]))

#expectedoutput = 22 22 
#'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: `'22 22'` is `MjIgMjIK` in base64

Comment: Did you mean to just use [`base64.b64decode(b6)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode)?

Comment: This is the answer:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583565/str-object-has-no-attribute-decode-python-3-error

Answer (score 0):

Bytes objects have decode function. Strings do not. The leading `b` on the string matters.

```
b6 = b'FhY='
```

Then, `decode('base64')` [is not correct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) and will return error saying the codec doesn't exist.

Here is what you need, which returns a joined string of two decimal values

```
>>> ' '.join(map(str, base64.decodebytes(b6)))
'22 22'
```

Comment: `ord(chr(c))` is a complicated way of saying `c`.

Comment: @Sören You're right. I was trying different things. Have updated